# Add Calendar Web Part w/SharePoint 2010 AND Summary View

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to add a calendar web part to the default.aspx page within a feature.  The calendar gets placed on the form but I would like the default view to be the summary view.  I have read that if you set the `ViewGuid` to `string.Empty` it will set the view to the summary view but this is not working.

Ideas?

```
//  Calendar
ListViewWebPart calendarWP = new ListViewWebPart();
SPList calendarList = site.Lists["Calendar"];
calendarWP.ListName = calendarList.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
calendarWP.ViewGuid = string.Empty;
oWPManager.AddWebPart(calendarWP, "Left", 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some digging and experimenting, I have found the solution to this mystery.

### Sharepoint 2007 (I assume this works on 2007)

```
SPList calendarList = site.Lists["Calendar"]; 
calendarWP.ListName = calendarList.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper(); 
calendarWP.ViewGuid = string.Empty; 
oWPManager.AddWebPart(calendarWP, "Left", 3);
```

### Sharepoint 2010

```
SPList calendarList = site.Lists["Calendar"]; 
calendarWP.ListName = calendarList.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper(); 

SPView summaryView = calendarList.Views[string.Empty];
calendarWP.ViewGuid = summaryView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
oWPManager.AddWebPart(calendarWP, "Left", 3);
```

Hope this helps someone else